# Memory Leak with CGImage and ALAsset

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, memory-leaks

```
NSData * pngdata = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageWithCGImage:selected.defaultRepresentation.fullScreenImage scale:1 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp],.6);
```

The above code is causing a memory leak every time it is called. Does anyone have any clue why? If I try to release pngdata that will crash the app I am under the assumption that the NSData is autoreleased anyway.

This is from instruments.

> Leaked Object #   Address Size    Responsible Library Responsible Frame
>   Malloc 16 Bytes 2   < multiple >    32 Bytes    ImageIO CGImageMergeXMPPropsWithLegacyProps

Comment: I've noticed the exact same thing but I could not generate it again on subsequent executions.